# Failed to login to icecast2 with oggfwd

Tags: ffmpeg, icecast

I have a problem, when i try to mix two source to one for icecast2. Oggfwd cannot login to the icecast server. I check the password, it is correct.
Here is everything:

```
ffmpeg -i http://localhost:8080/mix1.ogg -i http://localhost:8080/mix2.ogg -filter_complex "pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3" -f ogg - | ffmpeg2theora -a 3  --no-skeleton -o /dev/stdout - | oggfwd -p localhost 8080 *********** /hmradio.ogg
```

And the output:

```
ffmpeg version N-59015-g3efe5e3 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 12 2013 05:15:11 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/32bit --arch=x86_32 --extra-cflags='-m32 -I/root/ffmpeg-static/32bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-m32 -L/root/ffmpeg-static/32bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      52. 58.100 / 52. 58.100
  libavcodec     55. 45.101 / 55. 45.101
  libavformat    55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     3. 92.100 /  3. 92.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
oggfwd: Error connecting: Login failed
Input #0, ogg, from 'http://localhost:8080/mix1.ogg':
  Duration: 159957:31:20.33, start: 942.319456, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : mixxx/libvorbis
Input #1, ogg, from 'http://localhost:8080/mix2.ogg':
  Duration: 159957:32:38.32, start: 864.329433, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : mixxx/libvorbis
[Parsed_pan_0 @ 0x9f40ba0] This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items.
[flac @ 0x9fa6720] encoding as 24 bits-per-sample
Output #0, ogg, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.22.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s32, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavf55.22.100
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (vorbis) -> pan
  pan -> Stream #0:0 (flac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[ogg @ 0x8fd5480] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, ogg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s32
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavf55.22.100
WARNING: Can't get duration of media, not indexing, writing Skeleton 3 track.
```

Thanks.